# Why there is no partial function chaining method other than orElse

Tags: scala

I ask this question, because i found myself needing functionality similar to `andThen` of normal function (but still conforming to semantics of partial function). What i mean should be explained by the following:

`andThen` for functions:

```
val x: Int => Int = ???
val y: Int => Double = ???
val z: Int => Double = x andThen y
```

`andThen` for partial function (named differently because `andThen` already exist with different semantics):

```
val x: PartialFunction[A, B] = ???
val y: PartialFunction[B, C] = ???
val z: PartialFunction[A, C] = x andThenExtact y
```

Where `z` is defined on parameter `a: A` which has the following properties:

1. x is defined at a
2. y is defined at x(a)

I have came up with the following extension that should in principle provide the desired functionality:

```
type =>?[-A, +B] = PartialFunction[A, B]

class RichPartialFunction[A, B](private val lhs: A =>? B) extends AnyVal {

  def andThenWiden[BB >: B, R](widening: BB =>? R): A =>? R = {
    val InnerMatcher = matchArgument(lhs)
    val pf: A =>? R = {
      case InnerMatcher(res) if widening.isDefinedAt(res) =>
        widening(res)
    }
    pf
  }

  def andThenExact[R](pipeTo: B =>? R): A =>? R = {
    val InnerMatcher = matchArgument(lhs)
    val pf: A =>? R = {
      case InnerMatcher(res) if pipeTo.isDefinedAt(res) =>
        pipeTo(res)
    }
    pf
  }

}
private def matchArgument[A, B](fun: A =>? B): PartiallyUnapply[A, B] = new PartiallyUnapply(fun)

private class PartiallyUnapply[A, B](private val fun: A =>? B) extends AnyVal {
  def unapply(arg: A): Option[B] = {
    fun.andThen(Some(_)).applyOrElse(arg, (_: A) => None)
  }
}
```

My question is there better solution for this problem, and if my approach is bad then how could i replace `x andThenExtact y` in my code?

Comment: Scala has a `compose` operator that composes functions together. How does it differ from what you are trying to do?

Comment: @BobDalgleish `f compose g` is not a `PartialFunction` even if `g` is a `PartialFunction`. This is bad if you want to use `isDefinedAt` or any other PF-specific functions.

Comment: The problem I see with this is that you have to _evaluate_ the lhs before you can tell whether the result is defined. Consider `if(destroyTheWorld.andThen(PartialFunction.empty[Foo,Bar]).isDefinedAt(today)) drinkVodka`

Comment: @Dima That doesn't really matter, I'd say, as you can already include arbitrary code into a PF's `isDefinedAt`, like `{ case x if { destroyTheWorld(); true } => x }`. Preferably, it's pure and not too time consuming, and `compose` as wanted here will preserve those properties, but it's the user's job to ensure that that's actually true.

Comment: @HTNW in the grand scheme of things, it doesn't matter, you are correct. Actually, even the whole concept of a `PartialFunction` doesn't really matter - you could always agree to consider a function "undefined" if it returns, say a `null` ... It just wouldn't be as nice.
Similarly, in this case, It just seems semantically wrong to me when an API to find out whether a function is defined, ends up executing the actual function (and, to add insult to injury, executes only A PART of the logic).